# Why has this incomplete answer been able to stand for six years?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, specific-answer, wrong-answers

I have created a [WAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_%28Sun_file_format%29) file using Maven with `mvn package`. I have Tomcat 8 running on Ubuntu 17, and I was wondering how I would actually now deploy my application and see it work in a web browser.

It's just a WAR file with web forms and and a few views so, it shouldn't be rocket science, right? Um, wrong.

My journey starts here

1. *[How to deploy a war file in Tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109112/how-to-deploy-a-war-file-in-tomcat-7)*

This is the answer given: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5109133/7851085

The root of my Tomcat web application is `:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT`, so I was really expecting an answer.

The takeaway from that answer is:

> Deploying or redeploying of war files is automatic by default - after
>   copying/overwriting the file sample.war, check your webapps folder for
>   an extracted folder sample

I uploaded the WAR file which was `app.war` and visited `http://ip` expecting to see the application in action.

I even restarted the Tomcat 8 service. It turns out I can be able to download the WAR file so that is really not what I wanted.

Another answer to the same question is

2. *[How to deploy a Java Web Application (.war) on tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217693/how-to-deploy-a-java-web-application-war-on-tomcat)*

Another answer is

3. *[How to deploy a new WAR file in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34440833/how-to-deploy-a-new-war-file-in-tomcat?rq=1)*

None of the three answers says that the WAR file needs to be uncompressed via ZIP or JAR.

The first answer is particularly misleading since it's highly voted and incomplete in my opinion and thus "Deploying or redeploying of WAR files is automatic by default" does not answer the question.

Why has the first answer been able to stand for six years in spite of it being incomplete?

Comment: to me deployment to tomcat 7 works about how described in the top answer. I re-read it and your question several times and still can't see what specifically you find wrong in this answer (not to mention that it's about Tomcat 7 while you appear to work with newer version 8)

Comment: Is the answer useful to people? Does it answer the question? If the response to these questions is yes, can you explain why it *shouldn't* be left to stand for 6 years?

Comment: If you believe it is incomplete, why don't you edit it to fill in the missing information?

Comment: My contention is no answer explains how to unwar or uncompress the war file. That bit is important.

Comment: Should such answers also explain how to download stuff from the web? And how to copy files from one folder to another? At what point should someone answering stop from giving too much detail?

Comment: The part where you copy the files to the webapps folder for instance is mentioned in a lot of answers, but the uncompressing part is not there.

Comment: your contention doesn't make sense to me sorry. When I deploy (to Tomcat 7, which is what the question and answer are about) I only copy the war - no "unwar", no uncompress, unzip, jar extract, nothing like that. Tomcat 7 extracts stuff behind the scenes and I don't have to do anything. In that sense answers seem to be accurate about not mentioning this

Comment: "Tomcat 7 extracts stuff behind the scenes and I don't have to do anything." I have infront of me the latest ubuntu server on digitalocean, a war file and a console logged in to my account using ssh and i find that statement to be untrue.

Comment: well sure I heard about Tomcat _sometimes_ behaving like you describe for some reasons. However, this doesn't seem to be normal, typical, expected behavior - and votes on the answers seem to reflect just that. Not to mention that you did not even try to properly reproduce what is the question and answers about - using tomcat 8 instead of 7 is wrong in this context (note how they don't pretend to be about tomcat 8)

Comment: Given the fact that it doesn't work for you in particular, while the answers have been upvoted by multiple people - I'd argue they did help. Are you sure your main issue isn't just that you're putting your .war file into `/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT` instead of `/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps`?

Comment: IMHO,SO is loosing its divine significance when it comes to bite size howtos relied upon by thousands of developers. SO risks becoming a huge mountain of wrong answers,whether you admit it or you don't.  I have done my part in pointing out what i think is wrong and if my question seems like i am belittling anyone's efforts in answering questions,i can assure you its not it.

Comment: If you believe important information is missing in an answer - add a comment. An edit would also work, but suggested edits adding information tend to get rejected.

Comment: I guess it's the issue for those expecting one bite to be enough. "How to deploy to tomcat" is only the first thing to ask at Google which returns only the most likely answer (but not necessarily one that fits one's specific case). If one finds that what they observe differ, next logical thing would be to search further, like "Tomcat 8 doesn't automatically extract war" etc

Answer (score 4):

An incomplete answer is still an answer.

If you feel that the answer is missing crucial information in such a way that makes the answer an active distraction or actively harmful, you can downvote it. Mind you, it was good enough for over 200 people to upvote it in spite of this, so not everybody thinks the missing information was crucial to the answer. Indeed, one downvote probably isn't going to have much of an impact.

But there's nothing about the answer that suggests it should be deleted. It's not *gravely* misleading or insecure, it's not spam, rude or abusive, and it's not egregiously irrelevant commentary.